# How to get All user sessions in marklogic server?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I need to get all User session and related details in Marklogic DB server. Let me know if any queries or any other tool is helpful .

Regards

Comment: To my knowledge that is not exposed nor stored in any way, unless it is using custom code to handle user sessions..

Comment: If you could get the data, what would you do with it? Perhaps there's a different way to solve the problem you have in mind.

Comment: Well I am looking for what data inserted by what mechanism and who did that , just for administration purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate whether [Auditing Events](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/auditing#chapter) will provide enough of the information that you are looking for. There are a number of [auditable events](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/auditing#id_15948) that can be enabled, and you can [restrict auditing events](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/auditing#id_23562) according to a variety of conditions.

For instance, with `document-insert` audit event includes the URI of the document and the User that performed the action: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/auditing#id_15948

An example audit entry for document-insert:

```
2012-03-23 15:07:05.674 event=document-insert; type=insert; 
uri=/queries/5523898374388210414.txt; database=App-Services;
success=true; user=admin-xxx; roles=admin;
```

Entries are written to the `/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/AuditLog.txt`

You can also use the [GET /manage/v2/logs](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/logs) endpoint to retrieve AuditLog events:

http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/logs?filename=AuditLog.txt